# RxJava return to the previous scheduler

Tags: rx-java

Is there a way to ask RxJava observable to change its current scheduler to the previous after work has been done on some other scheduler?

```
Observable
        .just(null)
```

work is moved to the io scheduler

```
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

work is moved to the computation scheduler

```
        .flatMap(__ -> Observable.timer(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
```

So, here I don't want to explicitly ask for observing on the io thread but rather to return to the previous scheduler (which is io).

```
        .subscribe(__ -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

rxjava: 1.1.8

Comment: `subscribeOn` means that operator will subscribe the upsteam Observable on that Scheduler. AFAIK there is no way to affect only upsteam. Or you can use a combination of `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` to your Observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to return to the exact thread or the same scheduler? The former is not available in 1.x but possible in 2.x via [extensions library](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#sharedscheduler). The latter requires the use of `observeOn(Schedulers.io())`.